# UISplitView On iPad - Have I The Correct Structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Trying to introduce a **UISplitView** into an existing application based off a **TabBar Controller** to run on an **iPad** only.

I have the 'master' view displaying, but the 'detail' view won't show.

I have attached a schematic on how the Storyboard looks.

Do I have the necessary Segue's connecting correctly?

If you need the code to look deeper, please ask.

[image]

Comment: I have included a link to the ZIP file that contains the project. This may help out:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj28oym0cw9c7c1/HDBase.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project you provided, the Tab Bar Controller has `HomeController` and the Preferences controller set as view controllers. This is incorrect since you should have the Split View Controller for the Preference controller, as one of the tab bar's view controllers. Once you do that, you will have the split view displaying correctly.

Comment: Thanks Fahim.   Made the changes and now it's starting to look like something.   Cheers.

Comment: Happy to help :)